# What is causing "The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, .net-core, model-view-controller

I am trying to learn how to do paging functionality and have been trying to follow the Microsoft MVC docs but I keep getting the error

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The method 'Skip' is only supported
> for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be
> called before the method 'Skip'.

I have tried a few solutions I have found online and none of this has worked. Here is my code

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString, string currentFilter, int? page)
    {
        

        IQueryable<Production> productions = from s in db.Productions select s;
        //Searches database for matching production title
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            productions = productions.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString))
                                                   .OrderBy(s => s.ProductionId); 
        }

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;


        

        int pageSize = 3;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        

        return View(productions.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried order by outside the if-block?

Comment: If `searchString` is `null` or empty, it will not be ordered, isn't it?

Comment: This isn't a LINQ quirk. The `OFFSET` and `FETCH` clauses [are part of the ORDER BY clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned). Even if there's no `Where` you *must* include an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @tallberg No I dont know why I didnt think of this either thank you

Comment: @SᴇM Putting it outside of the If statement worked thank you!

Comment: Linq to entities, internally, converts the expression into SQL code, in your example, `ToPageList` internally probably uses `Skip` and `Take` methods, which will be converted into `OFFSET` and `FETCH` SQL commands. And as @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned, it is a part of `ORDER BY` clause. The reason you get the error is that your LINQ query is not being evaluated until probably somewhere inside `ToPageList`, it's called _**deferred execution**_.

Answer (score 1):

For paging, skip, ... first you must sort result and then you can partitioning it.
The Skip() method need ordered result.

```
IQueryable<Production> productions = from s in db.Productions select s order by DEFAULT_ORDER_KEY;
```

You must change DEFAULT_ORDER_KEY with your desired one.

**Tips for performance:** Use order key that UI need to show data by default to prevent duplicate sorting and prevent extra sort cost.